# Code check option to make VB.NET Readonly more useful

Tags: vb.net

Trying to program 'with immutability in mind' in VB.NET can be a challenge.

In many cases, creating classes with a parametrized constructor and properties with no setters is a pretty good way to create objects that are immutable (from outside the object).

Sometimes it would be more practical to just use the VB.NET ReadOnly keyword, but:

> If the data type of the variable is a reference type, such as an array
> or a class instance, its members can be changed even if the variable
> itself is ReadOnly.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/readonly).

Is there a code analysis tool or simple solution that can give me a compilation warning if for instance a string array that is declared ReadOnly has one of its members changed?

That would make the ReadOnly keyword so much more useful. Or is it possible to define such a rule myself in Visual Studio 2022?

Not striving for (functional programming-esque) purity but such an extra check to make the ReadOnly keyword more useful would be pretty handy, so hopefully there is a straightforward way to get such a code check!

Comment: You must make the collection items themselves immutable and use an [Immutable Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/march/net-framework-immutable-collections). See also [ReadOnlyCollection(Of T) Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=net-6.0).

Comment: I don't know of such a thing already existing, but I would imagine it would be feasible to write it yourself.  I believe there is a fairly extensive plugin analyzer interface, though I haven't done anything with it myself.

Comment: Olivier and Craig thank you, immutable/readonly collections are useful options as well.  The 'readonly' code check described above also covers object mutations on objects marked readonly so that would cover many other uses.

Comment: Actually even for Immutable/ReadOnly Collections the compiler code check I propose would be useful: "Note that both immutable and mutable collections do not offer any guarantees regarding the elements themselves. If T was Int32 or String, then the elements would be immutable, as well. But if T was something like StringBuilder, then the elements are very much mutable."

Because again here immutability is limited, and there are use cases where you'd want to know that reference types stored in for instance an array marked ReadOnly are changed.

Comment: For reference types collections, variables, and fields only store the references. Since you can read this reference and pass it to any method, it is always possible to mutate this object, even if the collection is immutable. The collection does not know a bout the method and the method does not know about the collection. Therefore `Readonly` does only affect the immediate value that is stored, and this is a reference for class objects.

Comment: Olivier I understand the challenge but I think the compiler can keep track of this and give a warning, it could mark anything that is referenced from a ReadOnly object/array and provide a warning when the object/array that is referenced is changed. Granted this could go many levels deep, actually wouldn't be a simple check but I think it is feasible. It would make ReadOnly more meaningful, although still potentially misleading. (as a check is still not the same thing as full immutability). But a better compromise is still better than what we have today